# How can I add a object property only in case a value is not empty

Tags: javascript

I have to add new functionality to add some metadata when the referral variable is not empty. I've made this, but something in me is saying that this could be done simpler.

```
async createStripeCustomer(user, refferal) {
    if (refferal) {
      return stripe.customers.create({
        email: user.email,
        metadata: {
          userId: user.id,
          referral: refferal,
        },
      });
    } else {
      return stripe.customers.create({
        email: user.email,
        metadata: {
          userId: user.id,
        },
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the duplication like the code below

```js
async createStripeCustomer(user, refferal) {
  const customer = {
    email: user.email,
    metadata: {
      userId: user.id,
    },
  };

  if (refferal) {
    customer.metadata.refferal = refferal;
  }

  return stripe.customers.create(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From memory of the Stripe API, null values in metadata will not set that variable in the metadata.

So you can just do...

```
async createStripeCustomer(user, refferal) {
    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: user.email,
        metadata: {
            userId: user.id,
            referral: (refferal ? refferal : null)
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is JSON data will have `referral` key in metadata

Comment: JSON data @NickVu? There isn't any JSON here.

Comment: these metadata fields will pass to stripe and store as key-value pairs. In this case, it may become `referral:"null"` (`"null"` is a string value)

Comment: As of 2020, null values act to unset metadata keys, so it ***shouldn't*** set! @Ivar the parameter of `.create()` is json :)

Comment: @Jordan No, it is a JavaScript object. [That is not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181).

Comment: Apologies, you're quite right. That's what you get for flipping between languages all evening!

Comment: bro @Ivar, you can check this document about how they pass metadata in Stripe https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Comment: I wasn't aware that you were referring to the payload that this call generates. My apologies @NickVu.